# SQL ORDER row BY row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to display music information from a database. I get the information with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT artist.Artist,
       artist.Real,
       artist.Genre,
       album.Album,
       album.Year,
       album.Image,
       song.Song,
       song.Feat,
       song.Time,
    CASE
      WHEN song.Song LIKE :1 THEN \'song\'
      WHEN album.Album LIKE :1 THEN \'album\'
      WHEN artist.Genre LIKE :1 THEN \'genre\'
    ELSE \'artist\' END AS "Case"
    FROM artist
      INNER JOIN album ON album.Artist = artist.Artist
      INNER JOIN song ON song.Album = album.Album 
    WHERE artist.Artist LIKE :1 OR 
          artist.Real LIKE :1 OR 
          artist.Genre LIKE :1 OR 
          album.Album LIKE :1 OR 
          song.Song LIKE :1
```

I am displaying the information in groups: artists, then albums, then songs. Only when I display the artists and albums, there are as many duplicates as there are song results. So I may tried to eliminate the duplicates by using this code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($row); $i++) {
  if($row[$i]['Artist'] != $row[$i-1]['Artist']) {
    // html content here
  }
}
```

I am trying to order the songs so that the most popular song is displayed first (adding `ORDER BY song.Click DESC` to end). So now, when the content is displayed, there are duplicates again because the `$row` before the current isn't always the duplicate.

That is why I am wondering if I can `ORDER` only the songs so that my duplicate eliminating code will still work.

Comment: You misguided yourself I guess. Please share the complete scenario.

Comment: Please ask a detailed question and if possible, provide a sample of code.

Comment: An edit has been made.

Comment: use `group by` to eliminate the duplicates

Comment: @Dagon Can you explain further?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT artist.Artist,
   artist.Real,
   artist.Genre,
   album.Album,
   album.Year,
   album.Image,
   song.Song,
   song.Feat,
   song.Time,
CASE
  WHEN song.Song LIKE :1 THEN \'song\'
  WHEN album.Album LIKE :1 THEN \'album\'
  WHEN artist.Genre LIKE :1 THEN \'genre\'
ELSE \'artist\' END AS "Case"
FROM artist
  INNER JOIN album ON album.Artist = artist.Artist
  INNER JOIN song ON song.Album = album.Album 
WHERE artist.Artist LIKE :1 OR 
      artist.Real LIKE :1 OR 
      artist.Genre LIKE :1 OR 
      album.Album LIKE :1 OR 
      song.Song LIKE :1
Group by artist.Artist,
   artist.Real,
   artist.Genre,
   album.Album,
   album.Year,
   album.Image,
   song.Song,
   song.Feat,
   song.Time,
```